# How do I prepare a skeleton for foreign animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

**What do we have?**
Both skeletons have similar structures, but they are not exactly the same. 
The source of the animations comes from the mixamo website.

I'll try to briefly describe **what I'm doing**:

1. I download animation with mixamo.
2. Import it into Blender.
3. Import a character.
4. I fix the character's skeleton (rolls by zeros, clear the quaternions of bones).
5. Rename animation channels.
6. Apply the action to the character.

[image: shortly.]
[image: shortly.]
[image: shortly.]

[Imgur. In images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvNZb.jpg)

**What is the problem?**. Scaling and renaming seem to be correct. The problem is with the skeleton. But I don't understand what exactly is the problem? Rolls? The quaternions? Which skeleton to fix and how? Request 'Throw the geometry on the rig and set the weight' please last.

**Tools.** I also have a script for renaming bones and animation channels. There is also a script for changing the scale of the skeleton without deforming.

[Google Drive. Animation n' Character](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSfICMSpyVfl3XMA222vV_zxRGgUhauY/view?usp=sharing)
[Google Drive. Scripts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhNnS0E8dGumh6WcWbuF1255X_yxHX_W/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: As I understand it , I need to replicate the skeleton as accurately as possible. But by changing the bones, the posture itself will change. I come to the conclusion that it is necessary, at least, to set as accurate a scale as possible and do something else to get the minimum loss, well, or at least an argument why this is impossible. Maybe I need to fix something in the graph editor? To get the minimum deformation.

Comment: Hi. Any images that you think are relevant to explaining your question better should be included in the question body as well and not in an external link. Thanks. (Also, I don't know what "'Throw the meat on the skeleton and set the weight' please last" means).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would really be nice to immediately attach the images, and not resort to using third-party services, but this was done so as not to overload the post and if something is not clear, you could follow the link for clarification and download materials from the file hosting to reproduce the problem yourself in case it’s still not clear. I hope you got what I meant. In any case, I can upload images if that is better. Regarding meat) I don’t want to make a “new” rig, but to adapt the existing one, so please do not recommend this method if there is no urgent need for it.Thnx.